# Issues with trying to make api call using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

The idea is to make a GET call from a third-party API site using redux. I would like to know what I'm doing wrong as I'm getting the following issues:

1. The API is not getting called at all.
2. I get an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: selector.map is not a function` at line 15 in the screen.jsx file when I run it.

Also, please note that I'm absolutely new to redux and having an absolutely hard time with it.
Here is my code:

screen.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getData } from "./actions";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const Screen = () => {
    const selector = useSelector(state => state.get);

    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {selector.map((key, value) => <ul>
                <li>{selector[value].name}</li>
            </ul>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

export default Screen;

actions

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export const getData = () => async() => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    await fetch('https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1/airlines', {
        method : 'GET'
    }).then(
        res => res.json()
    ).then(
        data => dispatch({
            type : "GET_DATA",
            payload : data
        })
    );
};
```

reducer(GET_DATA)

```
const initialState = {
    airlines: []
};

const FetchData = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "GET_DATA":
            return {
                ...state,
                airlines: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default FetchData;
```

reducer(index.js)

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import FetchData from "./fetchData";

const reducer = combineReducers({
    get : FetchData
});

export default reducer;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore(reducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

Here is the response that I intend to work with:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Quatar Airways",
        "country": "Quatar",
        "logo": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9b/Qatar_Airways_Logo.svg/300px-Qatar_Airways_Logo.svg.png",
        "slogan": "Going Places Together",
        "head_quaters": "Qatar Airways Towers, Doha, Qatar",
        "website": "www.qatarairways.com",
        "established": "1994"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Singapore Airlines",
        "country": "Singapore",
        "logo": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/6b/Singapore_Airlines_Logo_2.svg/250px-Singapore_Airlines_Logo_2.svg.png",
        "slogan": "A Great Way to Fly",
        "head_quaters": "Airline House, 25 Airline Road, Singapore 819829",
        "website": "www.singaporeair.com",
        "established": "1947"
    }
]
```

Comment: why you are mixing both promise and async-await?, also your API response is inside `selector. airlines` you need to use map  `selector. airlines`

Comment: use this  const selector = useSelector(state => state.get.airlines);

Comment: @sojin do you mean selector.airlines.map?

Comment: Yes `selector.airlines.map( ....`

Comment: @sojin I see a completely blank screen with no errors on the console. Do you why is that?

Comment: update the question with the current code, or show me how you changed it, or add your code in a sandbox and share the link

Comment: Try not to use `useDispatch` in your action creator function, it's mixing different concerns. It prevents you from using `getData()` in a non-React context.